# Dynkin system theorem and independance of a finite familly to another $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X=(X_i)_{i\in I}$ a finite familly of some random variables, and $\mathcal{G}$ a sub $\sigma$-field on the same probability space.

we want to show : **$\sigma (X_i, i\in I)$ is independant to $\mathcal G$** ?

**My problem** :

- I do not understand how to use the *Dynkin system theorem* to show that $\sigma (X_i, i\in I)$ is independant to $\mathcal G$ ?
- Moreover why it is just enough to show for some   $\{i_1,...,i_p\} \subset I$ that the vector $(X_{i_1},...,X_{i_p})$ is indepedant to $\mathcal G$ ?

What I have done is probably wrong, but I have showed that the finit class of event $X$ is a $\pi-$system, and we know that $\sigma (X_i, i\in I)$ is generate by them, but I do not understand where the *Dynkin system* and the *Dynkin system theorem* are used. Probably something I miss in my course ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the result you need is that the independence of $\pi$-systems implies the independence of their induced $\sigma$-algebras. So, if $A$ is a $\pi$-system generated by the finite vectors $(X_{i_1}, ..., X_{i_p})$ as you have described, then by showing that $A$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ will imply that $\sigma(A) = \sigma(X_i, i \in I)$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \mathcal{G}$ (note that since $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is a $\pi$-system).

Comment: But you dont use the dynkin system to prove that $\sigma (X_i, i\in I)$ is independant of $\sigma (\mathcal G)$ ? We do not need the theorem for this fact ?

Comment: The proof (which I know) that shows that independence of $\pi$-systems implies independence of their induced $\sigma$-algebras uses the $\pi-\lambda$-theorem (what you call the Dynkin system theorem). So, the result is still built on top of this powerful theorem.